# GWT Maven Plugin -- gwt:run works but gwt:compile doesn't. Why?

Tags: java, gwt, maven, requestfactory, gwt-maven-plugin

I'm using gwt-maven-plugin to manage a GWT project. I use the `gwt:run` goal all the time to run locally in "dev mode" for testing. I now want to compile my project into a war for deployment on Tomcat. When I run `gwt:compile`, however, I get compile errors that indicate a classpath configuration issue. An example:

```
Finding entry point classes
[ERROR] Errors in 'shared.MyClass.java'
[ERROR] Line 4: The import server.model.MyObject cannot be resolved
```

Any ideas? Do I need to manually add the `server` package to some config file somewhere? Thanks in advance for any info.

-tjw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. I found this in the GWT forums by Thomas Broyer (a GWT dev):

> I mean you have to "javac" classes that are *referenced* from
>   annotations  (in this case, the PlaceTokenizer classes referenced from
>   @WithTokenizers;  that'd be true also of your service, domain object,
>   locator or service  locator with RequestFactory, unless you use
>   @ServiceName and @ProxyForName).  Otherwise, GWT can work with only
>   the *.java files, without the *.class.

I am trying to load in these classes from annotations since they are used with RequestFactory. My question is now this: **How is this restriction not completely insane?**

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?  I'm hitting the same limitation.  BTW - this is insane!

Comment: Yes. The "secret" is to run 'compile' before 'gwt:compile'. So something like this should work: `mvn clean compile gwt:compile war:war`

Comment: your comment should be in answer also! it made my day:)